# Trying to deploy Ruby on Rails app on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the following error. How should I debug? I changed the database to MySQL and still it's not working. I also tried to use `.elasticbeans/ appname.config`, to tell to run bundler and migration, but it's still not working. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the link to the app and to see the error message:

http://mazzeyprod-env-wbyfpn2srt.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that bundler has not run on your production server even though you've issued a bundler command because it can't find rack.

Log into your production machine via SSH and run `bundle install` within your app root on your production server and try again.

Comment: can you tell me where can I get the AWS information required to log into my production machine via SSH

Comment: Thank you, although this did not solve my problem, but its very useful

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the github source link from the gemfile for the datatables, when I checked the logs of AWS EB, it showed error while installing datatables, when I removed the github link which it used to fetched the latest version of datatable. The problem was solved.